# Keep only the latest directory from many directories containing the same file

Tags: bash

I have multiple directories, all of them containing the same file `test1.txt`.

I need to find all the directories that contain this file (I guess the best way is to use: `find /path/ -type f -name test1.txt`) and then keep only one directory (the latest based on the timestamp).

Which is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
find /path -type f -name test1.txt -printf '%Ts\t%p\n' | sort -nr |sed '$d'|cut -f2|xargs rm -f
```

and if you want to delete the directory:

`find /path -type f -name test1.txt -printf '%Ts\t%p\n' | sort -nr |sed '$d'|cut -f2| \
 xargs -n 2 bash -c 'rm -f "$1" && rm -rf $(dirname "$1")'`

Comment: it seems that this one will remove just the test1.txt. Is it possible to remove the whole directory?

Comment: Added to the answer. You can use `sort -n` if you want to delete the oldest. And you can use `xargs -n 2 bash -c 'rm -rf $(dirname "$1")'` at the end pipe. Just wanted to show that you can  delete files and/or directories.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the files, use `head` to remove the newest, and delete the other directories. You can test this by removing the final `| bash`, and added it to the pipeline when happy it works to your satisfaction.

```
   find . -name test1.txt -printf "%Ts\t%h\n" | sort -n | head -n -1 | awk '{print "rm -rf", $2}' | bash
```